# 'TypeError: StructType can not accept object

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to convert this json string data to Dataframe in Databricks

```
a =  """{ "id": "a",
"message_type": "b",
"data": [ {"c":"abcd","timestamp":"2022-03- 
01T13:10:00+00:00","e":0.18,"f":0.52} ]}"""
```

the schema I defined for the data is this

```
schema=StructType(
  [
   StructField("id",StringType(),False),
   StructField("message_type",StringType(),False),
   StructField("data", ArrayType(StructType([
                  StructField("c",StringType(),False),
                  StructField("timestamp",StringType(),False), 
                  StructField("e",DoubleType(),False),
            StructField("f",DoubleType(),False),
   ])))
    ,
  ]
)
```

and when I run this command

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([a]), schema)
```

I get this error

```
PythonException: 'TypeError: StructType can not accept object '{ "id": "a",\n"message_type": "JobMetric",\n"data": [ {"c":"abcd","timestamp":"2022-03- \n01T13:10:00+00:00","e":0.18,"f":0.52=} ]' in type <class 'str'>'. Full traceback below:
```

anyone could help me with this, would much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your a variable is wrong.

```json
"data": [ "{"JobId":"ATLUPS10m2101V1","Timestamp":"2022-03- 
01T13:10:00+00:00","number1":0.9098145961761475,"number2":0.5294908881187439}" ]
```

Should be

```json
"data": [ {"JobId":"ATLUPS10m2101V1","Timestamp":"2022-03- 
01T13:10:00+00:00","number1":0.9098145961761475,"number2":0.5294908881187439} ]
```

And check if it is OK to match name with `JobId` to `job_id` and `Timestamp` to `timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I fixed it but still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Issue is whenever you're passing the `string` object to `struct` schema it expects `RDD([StringType, StringType,...])` however, in your current scenario it is getting just `string` object. In order to fix it first you need to convert your `string` to a `json` object and from there you'll need to create a `RDD`. See the below logic for details  -

**Input Data** -

```
a =  """{"run_id": "1640c68e-5f02-4f49-943d-37a102f90146",
         "message_type": "JobMetric",
         "data": [ {"JobId":"ATLUPS10m2101V1","timestamp":"2022-03-01T13:10:00+00:00",
                    "score":0.9098145961761475,
                    "severity":0.5294908881187439
                    } 
                  ]
          }"""
```

Converting to a RDD using `json` object -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json

schema=StructType(
  [
   StructField("run_id",StringType(),False),
    StructField("message_type",StringType(),False),
   StructField("data", ArrayType(StructType([
                  StructField("JobId",StringType(),False),
                  StructField("timestamp",StringType(),False), 
                  StructField("score",DoubleType(),False),
                  StructField("severity",DoubleType(),False),
   ])))
    ,
  ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=sc.parallelize([json.loads(a)]),schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Output** -

```
+------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|run_id                              |message_type|data                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1640c68e-5f02-4f49-943d-37a102f90146|JobMetric   |[{ATLUPS10m2101V1, 2022-03-01T13:10:00+00:00, 0.9098145961761475, 0.5294908881187439}]|
+------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```